# python style question

Tags: python, coding-style

Is it better to pass in a zipped list of pairs, or two lists that must agree in length?

With two lists, I have to assert their lengths agree, but at least the parameters are named.

I am asking about the prevailing style.  Are there any examples of choosing one over the other from major libraries?  For example, I guess matplotlib passes in two arrays.

Comment: Never use `assert` for parameter validation.  It's meant to be used for debugging.

Comment: what should I do for parameter validation?

Comment: In Python, [you should do *nothing* to validate your parameters more often than not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913819/how-should-i-correctly-handle-exceptions-in-python3/2913895#2913895).  And if you really have to, use `if` and throw an appropriate exception rather than an `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function is going to effectively zip the lists anyway, I would probably prefer to zip the lists in the caller. Then the caller can decide what to do if the lists are not the same length. Also, if your pairs are logically related then the caller might *already* have the data as a list of pairs, and it would be inconvenient to have to unzip it first.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion it depends on the semantics of the routine whether these checks must be done in the caller or in the callee.

Comment: +1 this has nothing to do with python and depends very much of the purpose of the code.