# Python print last traceback only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback

Consider the following code and traceback:

```
>>> try:
...  raise KeyboardInterrupt
... except KeyboardInterrupt:
...  raise Exception
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
Exception
>>>
```

I'd like to print only the most recent traceback (the one in which `Exception` was raised).
How can this be achieved?

---

From the above example, I'd like to print the following, as if `raise Exception` had been called outside the `except` clause.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
Exception
```

Comment: By "get", do you mean get the exception object, or do you mean not printing the context information? If you mean the second, do you want some sort of global interpreter setting, or something that applies to specific exceptions?

Comment: [Raising exceptions when an exception is already present in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278426/raising-exceptions-when-an-exception-is-already-present-in-python-3)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The perfect question for me.

You can suppress the exception context, that is the first part of the traceback, by explicitly raising the exception `from None`:

```
>>> try:
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
    except:
        raise Exception from None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 4, in <module>
    raise Exception from None
Exception
```

This was formalized in [PEP 409](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0409/) and further improved in [PEP 415](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0415/). The [original bug request](http://bugs.python.org/issue6210) for this was filed by myself btw.

---

Note that suppressing the context will not actually *remove* the context from the new exception. So you can still access the original exception:

```
try:
    try:
        raise Exception('inner')
    except:
        raise Exception('outer') from None
except Exception as e:
    print(e.__context__) # inner
```