# How to not have "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:" while defining its own class of exception?

Tags: python, class, exception, try-catch, raise

Basically I defined a new class of exception

```
class DirectoryError(FileNotFoundError):
        pass
```

this class is part of the more general error class FileNotFoundError, that already exists in python.

In my code i'm trying something like this :

```
try : 
   shutil.copy(dir,dir)
except FileNotFoundError:
   raise DirectoryError("not the good directory")
```

but then python tells me that there is an error two times, one with the FileNotFound error message, and then, after saying "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:", it tells the error again, this time with the DirectoryError message.

How can I do to only show my error message, and not both ?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725410/1145339