# Is there a way to only show the last exception in a nested exception chain when pytest fails

Tags: python, pytest

How can I return from pytest without showing the TimeoutException only the AssertException?

```
try:
  el = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@name='claims']")))
except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
  assert False, "passportmock not working"
```

This gives:

```
tests\test_12_passport_mock.py:156: in test02_passportmock
    el = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@name='claims']")))
..\..\venvs\<testproject>\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:90: in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E   selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
E   Stacktrace:
..<pointless long stacktrace and backtrace from webdriver removed>
E       RtlClearBits [0x7709BABF+191]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
tests\test_12_passport_mock.py:158: in test02_passportmock
    assert False, "passportmock not working"
E   AssertionError: passportmock not working
E   assert False
```

How can I get rid of the first stacktrace in the log and still fail the tests?
I've tested `pytest.exit("reason",-1)` in place of the assert, but then the test is ok.

A workaround is to use a variable so we get a single nested exception:

```
all_ok = True
try:
  el = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@name='claims']")))
  except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
  all_ok = False
if not all_ok:
  assert False, "passportmock not working"
```

gives:

```
tests\test_12_passport_mock.py:161: in test02_passportmock
    assert False, "passportmock not working"
E   AssertionError: passportmock not working
E   assert False
```

Would like to have a simpler way.

Comment: What you are looking for is `raise e from None`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725278/during-handling-of-the-above-exception-another-exception-occurred

Comment: Does this answer your question? [During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725278/during-handling-of-the-above-exception-another-exception-occurred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you raise `AssertionError` explicitly you can use [from None](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-409-suppressing-exception-context)

```
try:
    raise TimeoutException
except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
    raise AssertionError("passportmock not working") from None
```

Output

```
>           raise AssertionError("passportmock not working") from None
E           AssertionError: passportmock not working
```